# Grails cannot render GSP included from a plugin

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I have a plugin called `TestPlugin` that provides a GSP include in `grails-app/views` called `_test-include.gsp`. I'm importing `TestPlugin` into `TestApp` and trying to render it like this:

```
<g:render template="_test-include" plugin="${applicationContext.getBean('pluginManager').getGrailsPlugin('testPlugin')}"/>
```

I've also tried this:

```
<g:render template="_test-include" plugin="testPlugin"/>
```

Both result in an exception being thrown. Here's the error report from Grails:

```
Message: Error mapping onto view [/index]: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <g:render>: null
    Line | Method
->> 1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    617 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <g:render>: null
->>  527 | runWorker in C:\temp\grails-test\test-app\grails-app\views\index.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Caused by GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <g:render>: null
->>  113 | doCall    in C:/temp/grails-test/test-app/grails-app/views/index.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Caused by NullPointerException: null
->>  936 | get       in java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    141 | getValue  in grails.util.CacheEntry
|     81 | getValue  in     ''
|     58 | doCall    in C__temp_grails_test_test_app_grails_app_views_index_gsp$_run_closure2
|     70 | run . . . in C__temp_grails_test_test_app_grails_app_views_index_gsp
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't render your template starting with `_`.

this should work:

```
<g:render template="/test-include" plugin="testPlugin"/>
```